# How to filter through a longer list within the AutoComplete function on discord.py

Tags: autocomplete, discord.py

As there is a cap of 25 things being able to be shown at a time, how does a bot such as dank memer (see video) filter through a whole list a narrow it down just to show 25? If you know please show me, with examples so I can grasp the concept fully, thanks.

https://youtu.be/F1lUTD64RNU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the fuzzywuzzy package...

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
 
@yourbotname.slash_command(name="team", description="View 200 Teams")
async def team(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, team: str):
    ::all your juicy code goes here::
 
# AUTOCOMPLETE
@team.autocomplete("team")
async def team_autocomp(inter: disnake.CommandInteraction, team: str):
# Remember to copy process.py from fuzzy site-packages
string = team.lower()
def get_matches(string, choices, limit=25):
    results = process.extract(string, choices, limit=limit)
    return results
matches = get_matches(string, alpha_teams)
good_matches = []
for item in matches:
    if int(item[1]) > 40:
        good_matches.append(item[0])
return good_matches
```

So the autocomplete in this example is looking at the list `alpha_teams` containing over 200 items, which will return the 25 best matches. The only downfall is that the bot will not initially populate any matches. The user must enter a string for the bot to begin matching.

Note: I use disnake.py instead of discord.py.